# HUSOS HORARIOS INGRESANDO COOREDADAS GEOGRAFICAS (Latitud y longitud)

Tags: python, numpy

Me encuentro desarrollando un sistema de seguimiento solar, el cual hace uso de la hora estándar local para ajustar el modelo y obtener los ángulos de orientación requeridos. En mi intento de generalizar la función, me doy con el dilema de que hay zonas en las que el huso horario no esta relacionado con el meridiano local (longitud). Ver la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea inicial era ajustar el huso horario con la longitud de la coordenada, pero ya que es variable esto funcionaria solo ocasionalmente (en diferentes ubicaciones geográficas). Saben de alguna manera para obtener el huso horario de una coordenada especifica? Estoy haciendo uso de Python

Comment: Supongo que te tocaria consultar una api o hacer y mantener actualizada una base de datos con los husos horarios.

Comment: Cosas que los programadores creen acerca de las zonas horarias: The offsets between two time zones will remain constant.
OK, historical oddities aside, the offsets between two time zones won’t change in the future.
Changes in the offsets between time zones will occur with plenty of advance notice.
Daylight saving time happens at the same time every year.
Daylight saving time happens at the same time in every time zone.
Daylight saving time always adjusts by an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la operación para convertir un longitud (Este, Oeste) en las horas y fracción con relación a Greenwich:

```
horas = GMT +/- (longitud / 15)
```

Los valores se suman para longitudes al Oeste y se restan para longitudes al Este.

Ejemplo:

Santiago de Chile se encuentra en `70° 40' W`. Considerando sólo la parte entera (70°), me da

```
horas = GMT - 4.6
```

que corresponde con la zona GMT-4 asignada al país.

**Justificación**

La rotación de la Tierra toma 24 horas y hay 360° en una rotación. Ergo, 360 / 24 nos da 15° por hora.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, y si tuve en cuenta la fraccion de los 15° grados, pero sucede que hay ubicaciones en la que el estandar horario no esta necesariamente relacionado al meridiano estandar. Por ejemplo en el mapa  que puse hay los puntos 12 y 11.5 por ejemplo, no cumplen con el estandar de los 15°